# Send messages via Graph API stop working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Am testing this method via Facebook graph api explorer 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explore
i chose my user and give him access to `pages_messaging` `read_page_mailboxes`  `manage_pages`

then choose certain page and method {conversatio_id}/messages with POST request
and send parameter 
message: "test test"

I got this response

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#210) This call requires a Page access token.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 210,
    "fbtrace_id": "C+Xo8LCuuLW"
  }
}
```

Facebook reference

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/conversation/messages

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261578841015508/ // In the future, please look through their current bug reports before asking, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue reported in Facebook API and fixed now!
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261578841015508/